# Calling Winsock bind always change the local port and never fails

Tags: windows, sockets, tcp, tcpclient, winsock2

Recently in a test server I noticed that the call to bind() function, with any specific port, always changes the required port and never fails.
In other server everything works as expected,
Below is the sample code I use

```
iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
    wprintf(L"Error at WSAStartup()\n");
    return 1;
}

ListenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    wprintf(L"socket function failed with error: %u\n", WSAGetLastError());
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

service.sin_family = AF_INET;
service.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.10.1.118");
service.sin_port = htons(27500);

iResult = bind(ListenSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&service, sizeof(service));
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    wprintf(L"bind failed with error %u\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}
else
    wprintf(L"bind returned success %i \n", ntohs(service.sin_port));

if (listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    wprintf(L"listen function failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

struct sockaddr_in sin;
int addrlen = sizeof(sin);
if (getsockname(ListenSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, &addrlen) == 0 &&
    sin.sin_family == AF_INET &&
    addrlen == sizeof(sin))
{
    int local_port = ntohs(sin.sin_port);
}
wprintf(L"Binding on socket...%d\n", ntohs(sin.sin_port));
```

Everytime the obtained port is different from the request one (27500).
I checked with TCPView that indeed the listening port is the one assigned arbitrarily by bind.

Any suggestions on what might be causing this behavior?

Comment: Isn't that how some firewalls work? The connection gets redirected to the firewall process and THAT process listens on the desired port? Check if a different process is listening on that port.

Comment: Hi, Chris. There is no active firewall in the server and the antivirus has been disabled too. I forgot to mention that the server is a virtual server over Hyper-V infrastructure